# Adding a Fixed/Static Header to a Navigation DrawerLayout

Tags: android, listview, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

Like many apps, I use the `DrawerLayout` code like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->



    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I have some user information above the `ListView` so I use the `addHeaderView()`.  However, this scrolls with the list.  I would like the list to appear that it is scrolling underneath it and the header stays fixed at the top.

Is this possible?  I have tried by wrapping the `ListView` inside a `LinearLayout` with the header code inside that layout as well.  This completely broke the app.  Are there any other ways?  I have actually seen Google do this in at least one of their apps (youtube).

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping your List in some kind of layout is the way to go. Maybe you just missed something. Try this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="right">

        <!--SOME HEADER-->
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```